# trigger an event on enter for element ui library

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js, element-ui

i am using a element ui library where i have add a functionality to open a popup on the key enter, it works on the click but when i use tabindex to go to that element and click enter, it does not work.

here is my code

```
<span role="button" tabindex="0" @keyup.enter="filtersPopUp">Open Popup</span>
```

opening a popup is happening with this

```
<el-popover placement="bottom-end" trigger="click" popper-class="xPopUp" v-model="xPopUp" >
```

`https://element.eleme.io/#/en-US/component/popover` documentation link